# R Frequency table with condition

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with two columns, "CaseID" and "Event" and want to know how often Event with ID=X is followed by Event with ID=Y. But I am only interested in consecutive events with the same CaseID.

The command

```
df <- data.frame(CaseID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
             Event = c("A","B","C","A","B","D","B","C","E"))
df
table(df[1:nrow(df) -1, 2], df[2:nrow(df), 2])
```

results in

```
  CaseID Event
1      1     A
2      1     B
3      1     C
4      2     A
5      2     B
6      2     D
7      3     B
8      3     C
9      3     E

  A B C D E
A 0 2 0 0 0
B 0 0 2 1 0
C 1 0 0 0 1
D 0 1 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0
```

C -> A and D -> B have different CaseID's and should be 0 so what I am looking for is

```
  B C D E
A 2 0 0 0
B 0 2 1 0
C 0 0 0 1
D 0 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0
```

Is there any elegant way to add a condition to the table-command, based on two consecutive rows?

Ben

Answer (score 2):

We can only tabulate consecutive `Event`s with the same `CaseID`:

```
> x <- diff(df$CaseID) == 0
> table(df[1:nrow(df) -1, 2][x], df[2:nrow(df), 2][x])

    A B C D E
  A 0 2 0 0 0
  B 0 0 2 1 0
  C 0 0 0 0 1
  D 0 0 0 0 0
  E 0 0 0 0 0
```

In case `CaseID` might be non-numeric:

```
x <- df$CaseID[-1] == df$CaseID[-length(df$CaseID)]
table(df[1:nrow(df) -1, 2][x], df[2:nrow(df), 2][x])
```